# Changing the height of the object being sorted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, multi-select

I have a JQuery Sortable list with the ability to multi-select objects inside the list and sort them accordingly. This works fine, and is even interacting with a multi-select draggable list, but the one problem I can't seem to find the answer to is how the placeholder decides its position in the list. I currently set the Sortable helper much like you'd expect:

```
helper: function (e, element) {    
    var elements = $(element).parent().children('.highlighted').clone(); //all the items which are highlighted
    $(element).data('multidrag', elements);
    $(element).siblings('.highlighted').remove();
    var helper = $("<div/>");
    return helper.append(elements);
}
```

But when I have more than one item selected, and I want to move them down a position, the placeholder does not change. I would like to solve this without changing the size of the placeholder, since I feel that that wastes space. To illustrate what's happening:

[image: sortable]

Is it possible to register the size of this object as a single item of the list? Or somehow refresh the list so that the sort works as intended? Once a new placeholder is created, this issue disappears, so maybe it's possible to force a redraw on the placeholder? I've looked into each of these avenues, but none seem to be working for me. If more code is required to reproduce this, please let me know.